# I deployed a contract to BSC (testnet) with Remix. However, I can't write to the contract on BSCScan

Tags: solidity, remix, bsc

BSCScan says: "Sorry, no public Write functions were found for this contract."

Here's the contract: https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x02fbff9dcf4afd02d592142f2b80e0434f5e7649#writeContract

It's a fork of this contract, which is writeable! Since it does in fact have public write functions: https://bscscan.com/address/0xb0b924c4a31b7d4581a7f78f57cee1e65736be1d#code

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You should try to write from remix. If it works on remix, the issue is with bscscan and not your contract. We can't help you if that is the case.

Comment: You have deployed the Address library, which aren't meant to be used directly.